# Linq Select all fields of inherited class and some fields of derived class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have classes `A` and `B` like:

```
class A
{
     public int a;
     public int b;
     public int c;
     public int d;
     public int e;
     public int f;
}
class B: A{
     public int g;
}
```

Now I want to select From table of type `A`, should I write all fields like:

```
B[] b;
using(DBContext db = new DBContext(){
      b = db.A.Select(x=> new B{
      a = a,
      b = b,
      c = c,
      d = d,
      f = f,
      e = e,
      g = somevalue,      
});
}
```

or is there a way to say that select All fields of class `A` + field `g`?

Comment: are these your actual table mapping types?

Comment: well of course not. these are example. I have tables with dozens of fields. I thought there should be a way for doing this repeating all fields doesn't seem right

Comment: what is the desried value for `g`? The select is fine

Comment: are they linked like foreign key?

Comment: if you don't want tedious mapping, and looking for auto mappers,  automapper.org

Comment: No they are not, assume that class is Users, and Class B is a class that is derived from class A and has an extra field named LastLogin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description of your code is a bit inaccurate, hence it is difficult to find out what you really want.

From your example, I assume that your DbContext has a DbSet of type A:

```
public class MyDbcontext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<A> A {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

And you want to construct a B with the A-data you can get from an entity in your DbContext and someValue.

Your example of how you would retrieve the A-data from your DbContext does not work, and I can't grasp how you want to search: retrieve by Id? by one of the fields from A?. To overcome this. Let's assume you have a procedure to get the data from the correct row in you table of A-entities:

```
public A GetTheAThatIWant(...);
public int GetMyG(...);
```

Now the neat way to construct your B would be via a special constructor

```
public B(A, int g)
{
    // fairly straightforward code
}
```

or

```
public B(parametersToFetchA, parametersToFecthG)
{
     A a = GetTheAThatIWant(parametersToFetchA);
     int g = GetMyG(parametersToFetchG);
     // rest is fairly straightforward
}
```